# Why am I hitting the Twitter API rate limit?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm working with the Twitter API using the code below and I'm hitting the API rate limit inside the loop.

My question is: how am I hitting the rate limit? I believe that I'm only making one API call when I'm assigning myFollowers and in the loop I'm just looking through the location value of each object in myFollwers which should just be server side processing.

```
 require 'twitter'

    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
          config.consumer_key        = "xx"
          config.consumer_secret     = "xx"
          config.access_token        = "xx"
          config.access_token_secret = "xx"
        end

        myFollowers = client.followers("mytwittername")

        myFollowers.each do |follower|
            if follower.location.include? 'New'
                print Name: follower.name
                puts Location: follower.location
            end
        end
```

Comment: Have you checked with a network capture tool to see if its one or multiple calls? Something like ngrep or wireshark.

Comment: This is the best option. While the client may seem like it should be a simple and single call to the API, you never know what is really going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by default, client.followers is not going load up the entire user entity for each follower, so when you iterate over the followers you are generating a new request and thus quickly hitting the rate limit.

Try setting :include_user_entities on the client.followers call to true and see what happens. See link to code/documentation below.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/FriendsAndFollowers#followers-instance_method

If that doesn't work, stop your script after your client.followers call and let us know what the myFollowers collection looks like.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. No luck with :include_user_entities => true. I commented out the loop and called the inspect method on myFollowers and below is a brief output of it. It appears that the myFollowers object contains info on about 19 followers. Pastebin showing some instance variables about the API call and 1 follower: http://pastebin.com/hZvKna6e